# Prove that : “A connected graph G with e = v -1 does not contain any circuit”

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How do I prove this? Using PMI or proof by contradiction?

Comment: I would probably use contradiction. A circuit is a sub graph with $e=v$, and for every vertex you add, you must add an edge to keep it connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove by *contradiction*. Assume $G$ contains circuits. Remove an edge from the circuit so that the resulting graph is again connected. Continue this process of removing one edge from one circuit at a time till the resulting graph $H$ is a tree. As $H$ has $n$ vertices, Number of edges it has equals $n-1$.

Now, the number of edges in $G$ is greater than that in $H \implies n-1> n-1$, which isn’t possible.

So, $G$ has no circuit.

Comment: That's fine, if the OP already knows that a connected acyclic graph is a tree and that a tree an $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. It is possible that the OP's exercise precedes stuff about trees. Alternatively, assuming that the OP already knows that a connected graph on $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges, you can give the same proof but you only have to break one cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof is by induction.  It's true for one edge and two vertices.  Assume that its true for k-1 edges and k vertices.  Then add one more vertex.  Since the graph is connected, the new vertex must be the neighbor of one of the original $k$ vertices.  It cannot be the neighbor of two distinct vertices because then the new graph would have two edges connecting the same two vertices.  So the new vertex must have added one new edge.  Hence the new graph has no circuit.

Answer (score 0):

We shall prove the claim by induction with respect to the number $v$ of vertices of the graph $G$. For $v=1$ the claim is obvious. Now assume that we already have proved the claim for $v=k$ and a graph $G$ has $k+1$ vertices.

Assume that each vertex of $G$ has degree at least two. Double count a number $N$ of pairs $(u, f)$ where $u$ is a vertex of the graph $G$ incident to its edge $f$. Since each vertex of $G$ has degree at least two, $N\ge 2v$. On the other hand, each edge $f$ of $G$ contributes exactly $2$ to the sum for $N$, so $N=2e$. Thus $e\ge v$, a contradiction.

Therefore there exists a vertex $u$ of the graph $G$ with degree at most $1$. Since the graph $G$ is connected, the degree of $u$ is exactly $1$. Removing $u$ from $G$ we obtain a connected graph $G’$ with $k$ vertices and $k-1$ edges. By the induction hypothesis, $G’$ does not contain a circuit. Since the graph $G$ can be obtained from the graph $G’$ by adding a leaf, the graph $G$ does not contain a circuit too.